# Is it faster to constantly assign a value or compare

Tags: delphi, boolean-operations

I am scanning an SQLite database looking for all matches and using

```
OneFound:=False;
if tbl1.FieldByName('Name').AsString = 'jones' then
begin
  OneFound:=True;
  tbl1.Next;
end;
if OneFound then // Do something
```

or should I be using

```
if not(OneFound) then OneFound:=True;
```

Is it faster to just assign "True" to OneFound no matter how many times it is assigned or should I do the comparison and only change OneFuond the first time?

I know a better way would be to use FTS3, but for now I have to scan the database and the question is more on the approach to setting OneFound as many times as a match is encountered or using the compare-approach and setting it just once.

Thanks

Comment: OneFound := tbl1.FieldByName('Name').AsString = 'jones'; if OneFound then begin ... end; would be a bit cleaner IMHO, **but** you should look into using SQL to your advantage.

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo That changes the logic. The point about `OneFound` is that at the end of the loop (which we cannot see) it is `True` if one or more matches have been found.

Comment: From your statement "scanning an SQLite database looking for all matches" I infer that you are going through all records in the result set. OneFound get set if at least one match is found. Are you making sure that your loop is while (not eof()) and (not OneFound)? Because that is the real time saver.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I realize that the code as shown would be sluggish but that's why I mentioned in the last par about using FTS3. As @DavidHeffernan has answered, the question was about the OneFound being continually set as opposed to setting it once.

Comment: @JanDoggen, maybe I should have named that AtLeastOneFound :) I expect many more than just one and I want to scan the entire database.

Comment: Why not include such filters in your SQL statement's `where` clause?

Comment: if you really think of speed - you should use SQL, otherwise there is no point in using SQLite and u better just use DBF or Paradox ISAM. And at very least avoid using FindByName and other textual search commands.  `var f: TField; f := tbl1.FieldByName('Name'); ... if f.AsString = ..... then ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is, which is faster:

```
if not(OneFound) then OneFound:=True;
```

or

```
OneFound := True;
```

The answer is probably that the second is faster. Conditional statements involve branches which risks branch mis-prediction.

However, that line of code is trivial compared to what is around it. Running across a database one row at a time is going to be outrageously expensive. I bet that you will not be able to measure the difference between the two options because the handling of that little `Boolean` is simply swamped by the rest of the code. In which case choose the more readable and simpler version.

But if you care about the performance of this code you should be asking the database to do the work, as you yourself state. Write a query to perform the work.

Comment: But compared to the "tbl1.FieldByName('Name')" it is negligible.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen please see my last par about using FTS3 and a Virtual table.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to change your SQL statement so that the work is done in the database. If you want to know whether there is a tuple which contains the value 'jones' in the field 'name', then a quicker query would be

```
with tquery.create (nil) do
 begin
  sql.add ('select name from tbl1 where name = :p1 limit 1');
  sql.params[0].asstring:= 'jones';
  open;
  onefound:= not isempty;
  close;
  free
 end;
```

Your syntax may vary regarding the 'limit' clause but the idea is to return only *one* tuple from the database which matches the 'where' statement - it doesn't matter which one.

I used a parameter to avoid problems delimiting the value.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Search one field**

If you want to search one particular field content, using an INDEX and a SELECT will be the fastest.

```
   SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME='Jones';
```

Do not forget to create an INDEX on the column, first!

**2. Fast reading**

But if you want to search *within* a field, or *within* several fields, you may have to read and check the whole content. In this case, what will be slow will be calling `FieldByName()` for each data row: you should better use a local `TField` variable.

Or forget about `TDataSet`, and switch to direct access to SQLite3. In fact, using `DB.pas` and `TDataSet` requires a lot of data marshalling, so is slower than a direct access.

See e.g. [DiSQLite3](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlite3/index) or our [DB classes](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/22/SynDBSQLite3%3A-SQLite3-direct-access), which are very fast, but a bit of higher level. Or you can use our ORM on top of those classes. Our classes are able to [read more than 500,000 rows per second from a SQLite3 database](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/02/25/Using-external-MinGW/VisualC-sqlite3.dll-including-benchmark), including JSON marshalling into objects fields.

**3. FTS3/FTS4**

But, as you guessed, the fastest would be indeed to use the [FTS3/FTS4 feature of SQlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

You can think of FTS4/FTS4 as a "meta-index" or a "full-text index" on supplied blob of text. Just like google is able to find a word in millions of web pages: it does not use a regular database, but [full-text indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).

In short, you create a virtual FTS3/FTS4 table in your database, then you insert in this table the whole text of your main records in the FTS TEXT field, forcing the ID field to be the one of the original data row.

Then, you will query for some words on your FTS3/FTS4 table, which will give you the matching IDs, much faster than a regular scan.

Note that our ORM has dedicated `TSQLRecordFTS3` / `TSQLRecordFTS4` kind of classes for direct FTS process.